# Can I use more than one power/mutator at the same time?

Tags: goat-simulator

In Goat Simulator, you can unlock mutators or power-ups for your goat such as rockets or a ball launcher. While you can have one apparently active at the same time and use it via (R) is there anyway to switch between the two?

Comment: Switch; based on videos I have seen they just stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as many mutators active as you collect, in a normal mode, or select and collect, in a custom mode. However, be careful about selecting multiple mutators in custom mode, as character model mutators have a habit of conflicting with each other and making the custom game unplayable with that character.

Regarding 'R' mutators, unfortunately, there is currently no way to disable and enable specific ability mutators, causing all active mutators to trigger when you press R. For instance, if you have jetpack, devil, and pitcher mutators, when you press R, your demon powers and jetpack will toggle on, and a ball will be thrown.

Comment: *"For instance, if you have jetpack, devil, and pitcher mutators, when you press R, your demon powers and jetpack will toggle on, and a ball will be thrown."* to catastrophic effect.

Comment: To hilarious effect I think is what you mean. XD

Comment: Try a Tall Demon Angelic Jetpack Queen Goat.  It is a thing of horror and beauty.

Answer (score -1):

You can use more than one and everyone you got on you will be activated with R at the same time

If you only want to use one but already got another, i think the only way is to restart the game.